# How to move border-less window around?

Tags: haxe, openfl, haxeflixel

I made simple and small application with a clock using HaxeFlixel and native build. The window can't be resized or even moved because I made it border-less in `project.xml`.

The only way to move this window now is to hook to mouseMove event and set the window's position accordingly. The first sounds simple but the latter troubles me. I've been looking in Haxe API, OpenFL API and Haxelib but I can't find anything that could move the window around.

Here's the clock:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this project based on the function `Lib.application.window.move(x, y);`

https://github.com/RafaelOliveira/MoveOpenFlWindow

It isn't very smooth, I'm trying to improve that, but it's working.

Comment: I tested your code on Mac and it works! It's really jumpy, but the window moves :) Now I'll need to test it against haxeFlixel. Thanks!

Comment: I can see the problem. On mac and windows Lib.application.window.x and .y always return 0 even after moving it to the new position.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be a good time to use a [native extension](http://player03.com/2014/08/09/openfl-extensions/). But first you have to figure out what C++ code will move the window, and I'm afraid I can't help with that. If you can figure that out, the extension will handle the rest.

Quick summary of the link:

1. Run `lime create extension MoveExtension`.
2. Write your C++ code based on the sample code that Lime generates.
3. Compile with `lime rebuild MoveExtension windows`.
4. Include the output NDLL file in your project.

Comment: Along the way I added this to the nme native code, I don't know what the status of the OpenFL etc api exposing it is but, the code should be there https://github.com/haxenme/nme/blob/master/project/src/common/ExternalInterface.cpp#L1600

Answer (score 0):

Better answer:

1. Update to the latest version of OpenFL and Lime.
2. Add "`-Dnext"` to the command-line arguments. (In project.xml, that would be 
   "`<setenv name="next" />`".)
3. Now you can move the window: `Lib.application.window.move(x, y);`.